# Responsive jQuery restaurant menu system

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, jquery, html

I have a working restaurant menu system - as the user selects a menu it slides into view. The build is responsive, and I've used the 'Debounced Resize() jQuery Plugin'. However, in implementing the responsive code, I feel my code has become clunky, and it needs refactoring.

The hope here is that I'll receive some constructive criticism and some pointers on how to improve my code, which will in turn grow my knowledge base.

**HTML**

```
<section id="menu">
    <div class="menu-container">

        <ul class="menu__nav">
            <li class="menu__nav-item"><a href="#menu-name-1">Menu Title 1</a></li>
            <li class="menu__nav-item"><a href="#menu-name-2">Menu Title 2</a></li>
            <li class="menu__nav-item"><a href="#menu-name-2">Menu Title 2</a></li>
        </ul>

        <!-- Menu 1 -->
        <div id="#menu-name-1" class="menu__main cf">

            <h2 class="menu__course-title">Menu Title 1</h2>

            <div class="menu__col-wrap">
                <div class="menu__col">
                    <div class="menu__col">

                        <div class="menu__subcol">
                            <!-- The Menu -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu__subcol">
                            <!-- The Menu -->
                        </div>

                        <div class="menu__subcol">
                            <!-- The Menu -->
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="menu__image"></div>

        </div>

        <!-- Menu 2 etc... -->

    </div>
</section>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(window).smartresize(function () {

    var $mmenu = $('.menu__main');

    if ($mmenu.length > 0) {

        var $mnav = $('.menu__nav'),
            $mnav_a = $mnav.find('a'),
            m = parseInt($mnav.outerHeight(true), 10),
            $contain = $mmenu.closest('.menu-container'),
            h = 0,
            l = 0;

        // check and store if .active element exists
        var active = $mmenu.not(':first').is('.active');

        // if it doesn't exists
        if (!active) {
            $mmenu.hide() // hide all
                .removeClass('active') // remove the active class from any that have it
                .first() // select the first only
                .addClass('active') // give it the active class
                .show(); // and show it 

            $mnav_a.eq(0).addClass('active');

        $mmenu.each(function(z) {

            var $this = $(this);

            $this.css('height','auto');

            $this.css({
                zIndex: z+1,
                position: 'absolute',
                top: m + "px",
                left: l,
                height: (parseInt($this.outerHeight(false), 10) + m) + "px"
            });

            l = l - $this.outerWidth();

        });

        $contain.height($mmenu.eq(0).height());

    } else {

        $mmenu.each(function(z) {

            var $this = $(this);

            $this.css('height','auto');

            $this.css({
                zIndex: z+1,
                position: 'absolute',
                top: m + "px",
                height: (parseInt($this.outerHeight(false), 10) + m) + "px"
            });

        });

        var $new_contain = $('.menu__main.active').height();

        $contain.height($new_contain);

    }

        $mnav_a.on('click', function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var $this = $(this);

            if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {

                $mmenu.stop(true, true);

                $mnav_a.removeClass('active');
                $this.addClass('active');

                $mmenu.filter($('.active'))
                    .removeClass('active')
                    .fadeOut(250)
                    .animate({left:l+"px"}, 250);

                var $target = $mmenu.filter($this.attr('href'));

                $contain.animate({height:$target.height()}, 250);

                $target.addClass('active')
                    .fadeIn(250)
                    .animate({left:0}, 250);
            }

            $this.blur();
        });
    }
});
```

**Working Example**

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/samholguin/pen/snqgA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some of your code is redundant. These two lines are mutually exclusive. Especially since you add "active" to the first menu item, which is the only one which would satisfy !active.

```
   if (!active) {
            .removeClass('active') // remove the active class from any that have it
```

Makes me wonder if the "if (!active)" branch can be removed entirely.

Revised CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/FHfAi

Comment: Nice cleanup, +1

Comment: Thank you for the help, mutually exclusive code is something I haven't considered before. In terms of the   `if (!active) {}` block, this is in place to fix an issue I had when a menu other than the first was selected and the screen was resized

Comment: @SamHolguin I noticed that when I was working on the revised CodePen. By the way, I love the way your menu works. Nice job.